# Sum of column per distinct ID and group by different column

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have the following table:

```
create table orders (id int, order_id int, vendor varchar, price int);

INSERT INTO orders values 
(1, 1, 'nike', 10),
(2, 2, 'nike', 10),
(3, 3, 'adidas', 15),
(4, 3, 'adidas', 15);
```

I want to get the sum of the price per distinct order_id and grouped by vendor. So the answer here would be:

```
| vendor | sum |
|  nike  | 20  |
| adidas | 15  |
```

The reason why adidas is 15 is because we only grab one of the prices since the other adidas record has the same order_id.
Is it also possible to do this without a nested query?

Comment: What if there is another row (5, 3, 'adidas', 25)? The price is different. What would be the sum?

Comment: @forpas It my scenario, that would never the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Querying in two parts is pretty straightforward. First getting the distinct orders, then doing the sum:

```sql
WITH distinct_orders AS (
    SELECT vendor, order_id, min(price) as price
    FROM orders
    GROUP BY vendor, order_id
)
SELECT vendor, sum(price)
FROM distinct_orders
GROUP BY vendor;
```

If it's really important to you to do this with just one select, you can use a self-join, but note that this isn't actually a better solution:

```sql
SELECT o.vendor, sum(o.price)
FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN orders o1 
  ON (o.vendor = o1.vendor AND o.order_id = o1.order_id and o.ctid < o1.ctid)
WHERE o1.id IS NULL
GROUP BY o.vendor;
```

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres, I would use `distinct on` with `group by`:

```
select vendor, sum(price)
from (select distinct on (order_id, vendor) o.*
      from orders o
      order by order_id, vendor
     ) o
group by vendor;
```

Note:  If prices are different within a given order, this chooses an arbitrary price.

I suggest this because `distinct on` is usually the fastest method for reducing data in this fashion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a self `join` with `case`:

```
select o.vendor, 
    case when count(*) = count(distinct o1.order_id) 
    then sum(o1.price) 
    else sum(distinct o1.price) 
    end
from orders o 
join orders o1 on o.vendor = o1.vendor and o.order_id = o1.order_id
group by o.vendor;
```

Output:

| vendor | sum |
| --- | --- |
| nike | 20 |
| adidas | 15 |

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=51841496855c41488efc231a942dd1ae).

Comment: I think this still doesn't work, for cases when a vendor has multiple rows of the same order plus at least one row of a different order. But props for trying to do this in a single query, that felt difficult to me.

Comment: @BlueStar Hmm, can you post an example? I can't seem to replicate that.

Comment: @Ajax1234 for cases like this is what BlueStar is talking about i think: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=113a0e6e9b269f5469009b5410206d61

Comment: @tee what is the criteria for choosing a price in that case? Should it be the maximum price?

Comment: @Ajax1234 yes it can be the maximum price. In our case the prices per order_id will always be the same anyway

Comment: @Ajax1234 sorry maybe I wasn't clear. If the vendor has multiple order_id, it would sum it up. So in this example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=da4532655ae2481795c16a7a8401d0af 'adidas' should be 15+10= 25 because it grabs one of the values for order_id 3 and the other from order_id 4

Comment: @tee Thank you, please see my recent edit.

Comment: Don't hate me, but this still isn't fully correct. Summing the distinct price means that you might accidentally merge different orders with the same price, like in this fiddle where adidas should sum to 40: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9143acefca8542db8cc80107d021d61a